# iPhone build issue : MapKit/MKPolyline.h: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

I am trying to build the old SDK version based application in the new xcode. I have got the **MapKit/MKPolyline.h**: No such file or directory issue, the same issue is noticed for most of objective-c classes available under Mapkit.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no compatible framework in your new xcode framework path.
Please go through this [link](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=564),may be helpful for you.